# Add Friend through Facebook Dialog iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I've searched in google, but i didn't find anything about it.

In my iPhone app, on `UIButton` tap, I need to show a `FBWebDIalog` which shows a request to add a friend in Facebook account if the user isn't already your friend.

What do you suggest to do?

I didn't find any code unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code!

`NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     facebookUserId, @"id",
     nil];`

Then i pass this `NSMutableDictionary` as param inside the code below!

```
`[FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:nil dialog:@"friends" parameters:params handler:nil];`
```